# Android - FirebaseApp is not initilized with bucket name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am using two config files one is for Gmail sign and other one for FireBase. My problem is when I run my application it says like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{place.picker.mymarket/place.picker.mymarket.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp was not initialized with a bucket name.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2456)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5550)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

Here is my project config files structure.
[image]

Can any one help me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `google-services.json` file may not contain the Firebase Storage URL. This is possible if you downloaded the file right after creating the project, since creating the bucket may take a few moments.

The solution is to download the latest `google-services.json` from the Firebase Console, drop it into your project's app directory, and rebuild the app.

Comment: I have done that.even after doing like that. am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all google-services.json file then download a new one form firebase. make sure file name is google-services.json only. then copy new file and paste it. then clean the project .